# NoSuchMethodError aspectOf() at runtime from building with iajc

Tags: aspectj

We used aspectJ to get some metric on an existing application.  When building and weaving with AJDT in eclipse, everything works great.  But in the integration env. we use an ant script to build and deploy the application.

The problem occur on an ExceptionHandler i did to be sure our aspect would not throw exception and break the application

```java
@Aspect
public class ExceptionHandlerAspect {

    /**
     * Pointcut
     */
    @Pointcut("within(com.xxx.yyy.aop.aspect.*..*)")
    public void allMethodInAspectPackage() {}

    /**
     *  Pointcut
     */
    @Pointcut("!within(com.xxx.yyy.aop.aspect.ExceptionHandlerAspect)")
    public void notInExceptionHandlerAspectClass() {}
    /**
     *  Pointcut
     */
    @Pointcut("call(* *(..))")
    public void allClassAndMethod() {}

    /**
    @Around("allClassAndMethod() && allMethodInAspectPackage() && notInExceptionHandlerAspectClass()")
    public Object logException(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable{
        Object ret = null;
        try {
            ret = joinPoint.proceed();
        }catch (Throwable exception) {
            if (joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint")) {
                throw exception;
            }
            this.logException.info("Exception in " + joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),exception);
        }finally {
            return ret; 
        }

    }

}
```

Basicaly, i want to intercept every call within my aspects package except in the ExceptionHandler itself.

the ant build look like this :

```xml
<iajc inpath="${classes.dir}" destDir="${classes.dir}" fork="true" maxmem="${aspectj.maxmem}" verbose="true" showWeaveInfo="true" debug="true">
    <classpath refid="ajclasspath"/>
</iajc>
```

The ${classes.dir} is the classes directory where the javac task built the application and the aspects

From the result,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.xxx.yyy.aop.aspect.ExceptionHandlerAspect.aspectOf()Lcom/xxx/yyy/aop/aspect/ExceptionHandlerAspect;
    at com.xxx.yyy.aop.aspect.ecs.AspectBaseEcs.inspectLoginInfo(AspectBaseEcs.java:65)
    at com.xxx.yyy.app.es.security.Security.loadApplications(Security.java:172)
    at com.xxx.yyy.app.es.gui.VSDlgLogin.loadSecurity(VSDlgLogin.java:346)
    at com.xx.yyy.app.es.ApplicationSuite.start(ApplicationSuite.java:839)
    at com.xxx.yyy.app.es.ApplicationSuite.main(ApplicationSuite.java:501)
```

it looks like the ExceptionHandler was not weaved!!!

I hope someone can help me on this one ;-)

Comment: There is a more common cause of this error [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929716/why-server-complaining-about-aspectof-is-missing)

Comment: you need to weave both "aspects" and "clients calling aspects"!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally found the problem. Our Application had a dependency on common module jar that was containing aspect too.

The base package name was the same: `com.xxx.aop` and the base class we used for our aspects was the same name. So 2 `com.xxx.aop.AspectBase.class`  were loaded.

Since we used a flag in our Ant build file to enable compile time weaving at yes/no, one of our `AspectBase.class` was not weaved while the other was.

Answer (score 2):

I had very similar problem

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ....aspectOf()...
```

I'm using Spring 3.1.2 + Maven 3.0.4 + Tomcat 7.0.29 and at od times it happens that when I'm starting Tomcat I'm getting this Exception.

I have no idea why that happens. I'm using Spring Tool Suit IDE, but when I perform `mvn clean install` from command line (not in IDE) it somehow get fixed, maybe this helps someone.

Comment: Seriously man...I was searching for this issue for almost 2 hours...but only your solution worked for me...so giving you a thumbs up.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have forgotten to declare the aspect path. All your task does is to compile but not weave. And that results in the `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`

Below is a sample that shows how to use the iajc task with weaving:

```xml
<iajc outjar="demo.jar">
    <sourceroots>
        <pathelement location=”src” />
        <pathelement location=".." />
    </sourceroots>
    <aspectpath>
        <pathelement location="org.springframework.aspects-3.0.0.RC1.jar" />
    </aspectpath>
</iajc>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Actually, i can see that my aspects are woven.  Since when i decompile them, i see that aspectOf() and hasAspect() are visible in the decompiled code of my ExceptionHandler.  All these aspects are in a package inside the project.  They are all included in the inpath.  What are we supose to put in the aspectpath?  the aspecjrt.jar?

Comment: The aspect you want to weave into your code. In the example above contains a transaction aspect that weaves transaction logic to all methods marked with @Transactional. If you have your aspect in the inpath, it should also work.

Comment: Thanks again to take the time to respond.  Actually you respond to another question i have posted about aspectpath ;-)  But unfortunatly it still does not work.  My aspects are contain in the same project as the base code of the application.  so they are in fact in the inpath.  but still no luck with the ExceptionHandler having a NoSuchMethodError at runtime.  If i comment the pointcuts of the ExceptionHandler, everything works great.  So the ExceptionHandler is in cause... but why^  i still don't know :-(

Answer (score 0):

I had this exception when I used Spring Boot, but my configuration of AspectJ was done in the "old way".

If you are using Spring Boot, please make sure you have only a dependency **org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop** in pom.xml/build.gradle.
Then you don't need any additional @Configuration for aspects, you can simply do:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LogEntityChangesAspect {

    @Autowired
    private ChangeLogDao changeLogDao;
```

Answer (score 0):

For load-time weaving I needed to include the package of the aspect in the aop.xml

```
<aspectj>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="abc.xyz.MyAspect"/>
    </aspects>
    <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">
        <include within="abc.def..*"/>
        <!-- next line was added -->
        <include within="abc.xyz..*"/>
    </weaver>
</aspectj>
```