# Why server complaining about aspectOf is missing?

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I am currently trying to inject Spring bean in AspectJ like the code shown below, anyhow I the server (WAS Liberty Profile) keep complaining the method aspectOf is missing. May I know how could I solve this problem?

**application-context.xml**

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
<import resource="/context-file-A.xml"/>
```

**context-file-A.xml**

```
<bean id="loggingAspect" class="com.huahsin.LoggingAspect" factory-method="aspectOf">
```

**JAVA code**

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Is there an aspectOf method? You're setting it as a factory method.

Comment: According to the documentation, it is not required as it create internally by Spring.

Answer (score 7):

This is a common error when wiring up aspect classes. It means that your aspect class, in this case `LoggingAspect` has not been converted into an aspect which can be applied.

2 methods to weave your class into an aspect are using the [AJDT Eclipse plugin](http://eclipse.org/ajdt/) or the [Maven AspectJ compiler plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html).

There are 3 ways to weave aspects:

- **Compile-time weaving**: compile either target source or aspect classes via dedicated aspectj compiler;
- **Post-compile weaving**: inject aspect instructions to already compiled classes (Can be applied to JAR files)
- **Load-time weaving**: inject aspect instructions to the byte code during class loading, i.e. load instrumented class instead of the 'raw' one;

Before an aspect class can be applied to a class it first need to be 'weaved' into an aspect.

An weaved aspect class will have [these static methods](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/ataspectj-aspectof.html) added.

Comment: May I know how could I 'weaved' my LoggingAspect class? I am running an web app, not a JAVA console, could you share me a little knowledge on how could I do that?

Comment: What tool/plugin are you using to do the actual weaving? Here is a (relevant guide on how to set up aspects)[http://denis-zhdanov.blogspot.ie/2009/08/weaving-with-aspectj.html]

Answer (score 5):

AspectJ needs to weave both - your aspect class and the target class.

#### Weaving your aspect class

- aspect class will get [aspectOf() and hasAspect() methods](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/ataspectj-aspectof.html) injected.

#### Weaving the target class

- adds calls to those methods.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your AspectJ weaving process isn't working. So you're calling the `aspectOf` method on an ordinary Java class and not an AspectJ class.

A simple way to test this:

1. Weave with a tool like the Eclipse plugin [AJDT](http://eclipse.org/ajdt/)
2. Create a simple JUnit test with Spring.
3. Finally make it work inside WAS.